# Copy contents of a folder, but none of its subfolders?

Tags: windows-xp

I'm using the explorer bar (the bar to the left of the main folder/files section in an explorer window) to show folders.

I don't have access to open any of the folders, themselves (at least none on C:\ (the C drive).

For some reason, I do however have copy rights (I can copy the folders).

Because I can only see the folders, is there a way for me to copy the main folder, but not any of the subfolders?

A localized example could be how to copy all files in C:\documents...[user]\my documetns\ but none of the folders (ex. C:\documents...[user]\my documetns\my pictures...)

Is there a way for me only to copy a folder, but not its subfolders?

Comment: Are you sure you're not asking how to fix your permissions problem?

Comment: No... there is deferentially a problem there :).  I can copy the entire folder, it'll just take a while.  I can't however open up the file (at least not through explorer.exe)